# Get Location with Mvvmcross

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to get location in my application (mvvmcross/monodroid)
I follow this post : http://slodge.blogspot.be/2012/04/getting-location-information-in.html
I'm using Vnext version.
When I try to get location I have this message in output : "Location Service Provider unavailable - returned null".
I have this code to initialise location plugin in App.cs :

```
protected override void InitialisePlugIns()
    {Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Location.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();}
```

And in my ViewModel I follow the sample. I have to get location when I'm on the view so I added this code in my ViewModel constructor :

```
_watcher = this.GetService<IMvxGeoLocationWatcher>();
DoStartStop();
```

I did somthing wrong I have this message ?

edit: I use Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.0 7"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem might be, but some things to try are:

- does your device definitely have gps? And is it enabled?
- does your test app have coarse and fine capabilities declared in the manifest file?
- does another app work? Eg the mvx tutorial app with its location view?

Comment: Shame on me... I completely forgot to configure the manifest file ! I'll try it